# How to get Tensor Value which is define inside a function or variable scope?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I define some tensor as:

```
RESULT = tf.add(tf.matmul(Var_1, Var_2))
```

I can get the value of RESULT by using `sess.run(RESULT)`.

But if I define  that *RESULT* tensor in some function eg.

```
def fun1():
    RESULT = tf.add(tf.matmul(Var_1, Var_2))
```

then how can I get the value of RESULT? Same way if I define within a Variable Scope then What is the way to get value of that tensor?

Answer (score 0):

you can use collection I think:

```
def fun1():
    RESULT = tf.add(tf.matmul(Var_1, Var_2))
    tf.add_to_collection("FV",RESULT )
def fun2():
    RESULT =tf.getCollection("FV")[0]
    sess.run(RESULT)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the following worked:

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        ...
        op = sess.graph.get_operations()
        test = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("tensor_name")
```

- `op = sess.graph.get_operations()` gives you the list of all tensors used in computations. You can print it `print([p.values() for p in op])` and find the name of the tensor you're interested in.
- `test = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("tensor_name")` gives you the tensor with a specified name.